# Using chord to implement a torrent network

Tags: hashtable, dht, torrent

From my understanding, in order to implement a torrent network, you have maintain a map from hash value of the file to the list of peers available in the network.

However, I think there are a few problems with this.

1. the list will be changed constantly for it will be updated when a nodes joins or leaves.
2. the list might become very long? but there can only be one version of the list in the dht network(for it's a hash table)

Comment: Bittorrent already has am official distributed hash table for peer discovery based on kademlia. It is supported by most bittorrent clients. http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0005.html

Answer (score 0):

> You have maintain a map from hash value of the file to the list of peers available in the network.

That is correct and it's the purpose of the DHT. The DHT will keep information on who is on the network and who has a certain information.

> The list will be changed constantly for it will be updated when a nodes joins or leaves.

This is also correct but bit torrent DHTs are built with this in mind, with protocols for joining and removing offline peers.

> the list might become very long? but there can only be one version of the list in the dht network(for it's a hash table)

That's the thing with DHT, it's distributed so you don't need to keep the entire DHT in one place. You only need a find the information you're looking for across the network.

To join a network you'll need a way to find some peers and to request the DHT. Usually this is done with **[bootstrap nodes](https://blog.libtorrent.org/2016/09/dht-bootstrap-node/)**. Once you've contacted a node you will be able to share information you have and discover other nodes and get information they have.

Each DHT has its own algorithms, you can find some details for the Chord DHT [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chord_(peer-to-peer)#Protocol_details).